# Ionic show and hide part of text

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have long text coming from API and I wish to show part of it (possibly 2 lines of it) and allow users to extend the area in order to read full text instead of returning full text in first sight.

## Sample

This is what I try to achieve

[image: one]

## Code

This is my text part code in view

```
<ion-card-content [innerHTML]="listing.body"></ion-card-content></ion-col>
```

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle the height of your text container when the show more button is clicked. Make Show more button overlap your text container and this way you can achieve the effect you wanted.

**Template:**

```html
<div name="main" style="position:relative;display:grid;">
  <p [class]="show?'showText':'hideText'">{{listing.body}}</p>
  <div [class]="show?'showReadMore':'showReadLess'" (click)="displayText()">
    {{show?'Read Less':'Read More'}}
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.hideText {
  height: 20%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.showText {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: unset;
}

.showReadMore {
  width: 100%; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 30%;
}

.showReadLess {
  width: 100%;  
}
```

**Component:**
Declare variable

```js
public show: boolean = false;
```

Create Function

```js
displayText() {
  this.show = !this.show
}
```

Comment: hi, this works (functionally) but by design it has issue, see the screenshot please https://prnt.sc/q29b2h  as we're not using `innerHTML` it shows all html tags, also lines are overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a boolean value:

```js
show: boolean = false;
```

Declare a method to toggle the value:

```js
displayText() {
  this.show = !this.show
}
```

Comment: that way it hides it all how to limit the text part for show by default? `e.g.` show 150 characters and rest with this `displayText()`

Comment: You can do it simply by using slice method dear. For eg: let example="Hi, welcome to Angular "     let result = example.slice(0, 10)+'...'

Comment: thank you, i will test this method and let you know if it works or not